# Why is this regular expression in javascript still allowing special characters [a-zA-Z1-9 ]?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't want to allow special characters but this regular expression still allows them, what am I doing wrong?

When i type for name : **'&é"é&'é"&'&é"'a'**  It still gives back 'true'

```
name.match(/[a-zA-Z1-9 ]/))
```

Comment: anchors `name.match(/^[a-zA-Z1-9 ]+$/)`

Comment: last character i.e. `a` is matched..see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/pP0tJ9/1)**..do what @anubhava says

Comment: As an addition: you can check your regular expressions using this online tool: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with anchors `^` and `$`.

```
/^[a-zA-Z1-9 ]+$/.test(name)
```

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) return an array if match is found. In your case, `a` at the end of the string is found and array is returned. And array is truthy in the Javascript. I believe, the array is converted to Boolean, so it returned `true`.

Answer (score 3):

It returns true because the last character ('a') is ok. Your regex doesn't check whether the complete input matches the regex.

Try this one: 
    ^[a-zA-Z1-9 ]*$

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(name)) {
  // "your validation message"    
}
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
var nameregex = /^([A-Za-z0-9 ]$)/;
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

if (!name.match(nameregex)) {
    alert('Enter Valid Name!!');
}
```